# fill() and plot() give different results in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create 2 sets of images. The first set will be of random filled shapes. The second set will be the corresponding outlines of the shapes in set 1. I'm able to generate these images. The problem is that the outlines seem to be 'compressed', when compared to the filled shapes. I want them to be of the same size.
[image]

Here's the code :

```py
    # Generate 2 sets of 500 images each
    for image_num in range(500):
        print('Generating image ' + str(image_num))

        # 42 shapes in each image
        for ii in range(0, 42):

            # Get the coordinates of the shape
            x, y = method_to_get_random_closed_shape()

            # Get a random grayscale color to fill the shape
            color = method_to_get_random_grayscale_color()

            # Plot the filled shape in the first image
            plt.figure(0)
            plt.fill(x, y, str(color))

            # Plot the corresponding outline in the second image
            plt.figure(1)
            plt.plot(x, y, 'k')

        # Save the filled plot as an image
        plt.figure(0)
        bg_color = method_to_get_random_grayscale_color()
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig("filled_image/" + str(image_num) + '.png', 
               facecolor=str(bg_color))

        # Save the corresponding outline as an image
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig("outlines/" + str(image_num) + '.png')

        # Clear the plots to create the next set of images
        plt.figure(0).clf()
        plt.figure(1).clf()
```

I've tried specifying the size of the plot:

```py
    plt.figure(0, figsize=(6, 6), dpi=96)
    plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=96)
```

I've also tried specifying the dpi while saving:

```py
plt.savefig("filled_image/" + str(image_num) + '.png', dpi=96,
               facecolor=str(bg_color))
plt.savefig("outlines/" + str(image_num) + '.png', dpi=96)
```

But none of these approaches seem to work. Please help.

**Update :**
Fixed the issue. I was using `Axes.set_aspect("equal")` . Removing it fixed it.

Comment: Manually set the x/y limits to be the same? My guess is that the automatic x/y limits are different for `fill` and `plot`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `fill`s and `plot`s are positionned exactly the same; [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9hs2.png). You may want to create a [mcve], such that people are able to help here.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest . I was trying to create a minimal working sample and found that I was using `Axes.set_aspect("equal") `. Removing it fixed the issue. Thanks anyway !!